# Correct modal verb

Tags: modal-verbs

Please share your thoughts about this item from an exam.

**UPDATED**
<del>If it is possible for John to shift to architecture, he (should/could/must/might) shift to architecture.</del>

> It is possible for John to shift to architecture. John (should/could/must/might) shift to architecture.

So there are four options to choose from, please share your thoughts about why the 3 of them are not suitable and why 1 of them is the correct answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that quote is 100% accurate? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, so I am thinking that "must" is not applicable, but I am not sure about "should", "could", and "might".

Comment: Change your tutor. There's no way that the right verb can be selected, because the first half of that sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: Could you please explain what is wrong with the first half?

Comment: If the first half is "If it is possible for John to shift to architecture," then does it make sense?

Comment: Yes. And in that case, any of the four alternatives is viable.

Comment: Could we please [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23574/discussion-between-user1764381-and-andrew-leach).

Comment: @user1764381 What do _you_ think the right answer is, and why do you think so? We can help you learn better if you explain your thinking so we can correct it.

Comment: What kind of insane exam are you doing?  They can all work and would all mean different things.

Comment: @Barmar My answer is "might", I thought "might" is used for possibilities ("If it is possible...").

Comment: I have updated the sentence, please take a look, it is the correct one from the exam, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Mari-Lou! I still don't understand though why "could" is the only answer.

Comment: Look at the answers below, both explain the meaning and usage of "could".

Comment: @Mari-Lou: You overstate the case. Another way of conveying that it's [*possible for {something} to fail*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22possible+for+it+to+fail%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is to say [*it **might** fail*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it+might+fail%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Admittedly, the ***for*** version tends to imply *capability*, making ***could*** more likely in many contexts. But you can't simply dismiss ***might***, since it's also a "correct" answer.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I obviously won't convince you, but I still think you overstate the case. The problem is it's a bad *question* - the fact that there *is* a case for claiming ***could*** is idiomatically and/or semantically and/or syntactically ***more likely*** doesn't detract from the fact that ***might*** is at the very least ***credible***. This simply isn't one of those situations where *every* native speaker would reject all but one of the alternatives. We can and do use *it's possible for X to Y* to mean *X **might** Y* (by chance or choice) as well as *X **is able** to Y* (by ability)..

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm deleting my comments. I'm not disagreeing with you. Might is *also* an acceptable alternative. But in a multiple choice test I would advise a candidate to pick *could* or *can* if the question asks for a word similar in meaning to "possibility".

Answer (score 2):

I would choose "could".

Having said that, the questions as presented by the OP is a bit ambiguous. I am reading it as:

*If it is possible for John to move to Architcture, [you would say] "He (should/could/must/might) move to Architecture."*

If this is the correct reading, then could for possibility is the best choice. Should is for advice; must is a conclusion; might is a speculation.

It could be that the whole thing is one sentence as:

*"If it is possible for John to move to Architecture, he (should/could/must/might) move to architecture."*

If that is the case, I don't know the answer. "Could" would be tautologous, but the other three could all be right dependant on the speakers purpose and the context of the utterance.

Comment: +1 for *tautologous*. Which imho applies to both *could* and *might*, regardless of whether one interprets the statement as relating to *likelihood* or *capability* (or even *both*, since all relevant words including *possible* can be used in either sense).

Comment: I have updated the sentence, please take a look, it is the correct one from the exam, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

All four alternatives are valid (depending on context), but *they all mean different things*. Paraphrasing slightly for brevity...

> 1: *If it is possible for him to go, he **should** go.*
>   Speaker thinks he *ought* to go (if he *can*)
>
> 2: *If it is possible for him to go, he **could** go.*
>   Speaker is giving a "defining example" usage for *possible* and/or *might* (OR same as 4)
>
> 3: *If it is possible for him to go, he **must** go.*
>   Speaker thinks he is *obliged* to go (again, only if he *can* go)
>
> 4: *If it is possible for him to go, he **might** go.*
>   Speaker doesn't know whether he can go or not - but if he *can*, speaker believes he might *actually* go. OR speaker is simply giving a "dictionary definition" example usage where the comma can be approximately interpreted as *means the same as*, or *implies the fact that*.

---

Note that although it's somewhat "splitting hairs" to say 2 and 4 are "different", I think at the level of "probable nuance" 2 is more likely to be a "defining example". That's because in BrE at least, *could* is more associated with *capability*, whereas *might* is more associated with *likelihood* (*possible* can have both connotations, but in OP's exact context I think *capability* is a much more natural interpretation).

---

TL;DR: This is a bit of a silly question, because there is no "right" answer. Worse than that, by setting such a question, the [original] setter is bound to end up misleading students such as OP.

---

EDIT: The above text answers the *original* question. It's still a bad test question because we don't know if the second sentence is supposed to be a *restatement* of the first (i.e. - a "dictionary definition" as referred to in 2, 4 above), or an *additional statement* (as 1 and 3 above). Also, even if we assume it's a restatement/definition, both 2 and 4 are at least *credible*.

Doubtless the expected answer is 2 ***could***, because *It is possible **for** him [to do something]* more strongly associates with *possibility=capability* as above.

4 ***might*** works better with *It is **possible** [that] **he will** [do it]*, where *possibility=likelihood*.

Comment: I couldn't/shouldn't/mustn't/mightn't have said it better.

Comment: @George: Noting particularly [Andrew's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245059/correct-modal-verb/245084?noredirect=1#comment530462_245059), I was initially inclined to closevote. But he's a mod, and *he* didn't close it (nor had anyone else cvt'd in the hour before I got here), so I thought someone had better spell things out. I just hope OP didn't pay good money to be taught/tested by such an incompetent teacher/examiner.

Comment: Word.  In a way, I could even see this being some American standardized test.  I haven't done any for learning English, but I've seen similar questions on, for example, the ACT, for which they want you to select the "best" answer, whatever that is.

Comment: Hi everyone, I thought "might" is used for "possibility", am I wrong?

Comment: I have updated the sentence, please take a look, it is the correct one from the exam, sorry.

Comment: @user1764381: If you're still having trouble understanding how *possible* is used in the two different senses of *probability/likelihood* and *ability/capacity*, I think you should ask again on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). It's not really what ELU is all about.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers! I still don't understand though why "could" is the best answer.

Comment: @user1764381: I think because *could* is the "past tense" of *can* (and *can't* usually means *is **unable** to*, not *isn't **likely** to*). Whereas *might* is like *may*, so if you ***might** do something* whether you *actually* do it or not is more likely to be a matter of choice or happenstance, rather than capability. But I still think you should seek a fully-fledged answer on ELL, not just rely on ephemeral comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of tautology:

**If possible... he could** means 
'If he can make the change he can make the change'

or non-sequitur,

**If possible... he must** means
If it is possible ... it is inevitable.

But **If possible... he might**  seems to me a polite way of suggesting that he should seriously consider the option. And of course politeness is no longer acceptable. It is an eliptical version of 'If it is possible... he might consider...

So in this transparent world, choose the protasis which says 'deepending on the statutory, conventional, financial situation, i.e **if possible... he should** go for it.

Comment: Hi Hugh, thanks. But because there is only one answer in this exam question, could you please tell what is your answer?